# Restart application server after WAR redeployment on Websphere

Tags: java, deployment

Currently I'm supporting a web application project where every time there's a production deployment, we have to restart the Application Server. I ask my colleague why and he said, deployment takes a lot of memory therefore restart is to avoid outOfMemory and PermGen error. I also found out that JBoss AS, we also doing the same - have to restart after deployment. In Tomcat, we stop the app server then do the deployment and then restart the app server.

Is it by standard Webpshere and JBoss or any other Java Application Server have to restart after deployment?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is by no way a standard. A redeployment may mean some time offline when the old code is taken offline and updated, but having to restart the complete server is normally no must.

Comment: Got it, "restart app server after deployment is not standard". How about outOfMemory or PermGen? Does it happens after deployment?

Comment: Normally this should not happen because of a deployment. Sometimes applications waste memory which sums up over time. So using a deployment which causes a short downtime anyway and combine it with a restart too is often a good idea.